# Issues while updating AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml

Tags: android, python, xml, kivy, buildozer

I am trying to updating `AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml` in kivy

which is located at some `/root/./~buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/dist/my_app/`

Basically i am trying to put ad buddies ads in my app

I found instructions at here : https://publishers.adbuddiz.com/pub_portal/sdk/kivy

when i go to 4th step:
and then try to put

```html
   <activity android:name="com.purplebrain.adbuddiz.sdk.AdBuddizActivity" 
             android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

in my `AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml` and went back to terminal and type

`buildozer android debug`

so it just remove the update i did in `AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml` so how can i use that code in `AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml`? .. so i am not getting ads in my app

is there any way to update `AndroidManifest.tmpl.xml` and make app ?

Comment: Can you explain better your question? I did not understand exactly what you meant.

Comment: When i edit in androidmenshfeild.xml and save it and then run command buildozer android debug it revert to original

Comment: My all changes to android menshfeild.xml were gone

Comment: any luck solving this issue? I'm facing the same thing here